# How to Search in recyclerview with One Adapter in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I want to search in `recyclerview`.

I write the Filter method in `recyclerview` adapter like this:

```
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Info_Filter> results = new ArrayList<Info_Filter>();
                if (orig == null)
                    orig = items;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (orig != null & orig.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Info_Filter g : orig) {
                            if (g.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                items = (ArrayList<Info_Filter>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Its ok, now I have another `recycler` that work with this adapter and this data model. Each one have a edit text to search. when I write something in first edit text, `recyclerview` number 2 changes.

How I can search for both `recyclers`?

Comment: simply use two different instances of your adapter

Comment: If this is inside the adapter class, you need to create 2 instances of the adapter

Answer (score 0):

First, create a class which extends Filter

```
public class NewFilter extends Filter {

    private recyclerAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Info_Filter> filterList;

    NewFilter(ArrayList<Info_Filter> filterList, recyclerAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.filterList = filterList;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<Info_Filter> filteredInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++) {
                if (filterList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    filteredInfo.add(filterList.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.count = filteredInfo.size();
            results.values = filteredInfo;
        } else {
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;

        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        adapter.mDataSet = (ArrayList<Info_Filter>) results.values;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Now implement the Filterable interface to your RecyclerView Adapter and override the getFilter() method.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new NewFilter(filterMDataSet, this);
    }
    return filter;
}
```

filterMDataSet can be a copy of the ArrayList that you pass to the adapter when setting the adapter to you recyclerview. You could create another ArrayList in the adapter and initialize it in the constructor with the same data as the main ArrayList.

Now its tike to filter the results using a text. You can run this code with the text that you need to filter.

```
if (recyclerView.getAdapter() != null) {
    ((YourAdapter) yourAdapter).getFilter().filter(text_to_filter);
}
```

Check if this works?

Comment: what is "mDataSet" in `adapter.mDataSet = (ArrayList<Info_Filter>) results.values;` ?

Comment: Its the main ArrayList of the recycler adapter.